# I wish to keep/discard items in a PURRR nested list based on a sublist within each grouped level

Tags: r, purrr

I have sets of weather station data which I wish to compare by site. I need to do this efficiently because each set is large and I wish to build my experience with PURRR. My issue concerns use of the keep/discard (or list.exclude (rlist)) to remove days (id) with incomplete data - it should be a doozy but I can't get the syntax right. I have tried to approach this problem by computing the dimensions of each tibble, and then use the length to give me a unitary list). I am using R 3.6.1 on a PC running Windows 10. Here is a trivial example. I wish 'mylist' to comprise id = 'a' only in this example.

```
mylist <- tibble(id = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",4)),
                 dl = c(seq(1,5,1), seq(1,4,1)),
                 v = c(seq(0, 40, 10), seq(50, 80, 10))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(ddim = map(data, dim)) %>%
  mutate(nn = map(ddim, extract(1)))
mylist
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
  id              data ddim      nn       
  <chr> <list<df[,2]>> <list>    <list>   
1 a            [5 x 2] <int [2]> <int [1]>
2 b            [4 x 2] <int [2]> <int [1]>
```

Comment: How do you define "incomplete data" ?  How id = "b" has incomplete data ?

Comment: Apologies, my simple example was too simple. The dataframe for each id has a variable length - column number same but row number differs and data within in each row is similar and missing rows may occur at any level. So filtering on dim() seems the best approach. map_lgl() requires a single value, hence I extracted the row number component of dim. So the decision can not be made on the 'data', it must be made on the derived values. mylist should have been random not sequenced :-(

Comment: If you want to filter based on number of rows, you can do `mylist %>% filter(map_int(data, nrow) > 4)` where it will select rows where there are more than 4 rows in `data`, you can replace 4 with any value.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how "incomplete data" is defined but since the question is more about how to filter rows where a certain condition is satisfied in a list, I have considered a temporary condition which is select rows where `v` column of tibble has first value as 0. This condition can be changed after clarification from OP.

We can use `filter` to select rows and `map_lgl` to loop over `data` column for each `id`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mylist %>% filter(map_lgl(data, ~first(.x$v) == 0))

# id              data
#  <chr> <list<df[,2]>>
#1 a            [5 × 2]
```

Similarly, in base R, we can use `subset` with `sapply`

```
subset(mylist, sapply(data, function(x) x$v[1] == 0))
```

**data**

```
mylist <- tibble(id = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",4)),
             dl = c(seq(1,5,1), seq(1,4,1)),
             v = c(seq(0, 40, 10), seq(50, 80, 10))) %>%
           group_by(id) %>% nest()
```